# How to wrap existing ActorRef by TestActorRef in Akka?

Tags: java, scala, akka

While testing akka actors system I instantiate it with multiple nested actors. As an entry point, parent actor produces nested child actor's tree. Similar to the production tree, but containing test data from H2 db source.

I need to verify a part of the whole system (let's say single actor state), that can't be accessed or instantiated separately form the others, because of data inconsistency.

I know, that for a standalone actor testing it is possible to get it's internal state by using construction below:

```
TestActorRef<RoutingRequestHandlerActor> fsmRef = TestActorRef.create(getSystem(), RoutingRequestHandler.props(), getTestActor());
RoutingRequestHandlerActor fsm = fsmRef.underlyingActor();
```

But what can I do, if actor is created indirectly? 
Is it possible to wrap it somehow to get an `Actor` instead of `ActorRef`?

As an alternative solution, I know that additional diagnostic messages can be sent responding with state description. But maybe there is another more intelligent way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to wrap it somehow to get an Actor instead of ActorRef?

It is not possible in a general case as Actor instance can be potentially created on a remote server.

> As an alternative solution, I know that additional diagnostic messages can be sent responding with state description.

That's what I would recommend you to do. Just send a special message, say RetrieveState() to the actor and add some code to the actor to respond with its application specific state.

That's the way Akka uses internally for similar purposes. Take a look at Identify message:

https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/Identify.html

```
case class RetrieveStateRequest()
case class RetrieveStateResponse[T](actorState: T)

...

class YourActor extends Actor {

  def receive: Receive = {
    case RetrieveStateRequest() => 
         sender() ! RetrieveStateResponse(actorState)
    case m => unhandled(m)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for detailed explanation